# invoke multiple services using stream lazily

Tags: java, java-stream

How can I use stream to evaluate multiple service calls only if the previous call returned null? ie.

```
Stream.of(service1(), service2(), service3())
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .findFirst()
    .ifPresent(this::doSomething);
```

basically I don't want all three service calls to be invoked if they don't have to be, and I'm interested if there's a better way to do this without a bunch of

```
if(service1() != null)
...
else if(service2() != null)
...
else if(service3() != null)
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that each of `service1()`, `service2()`, etc. return the same datatype, then you can provide a lambda expression that calls each service and returns that type -- a `Supplier<Result>`, with `Result` being that datatype.  You can alternatively supply method references.

```
Stream.<Supplier<Result>>of(YourService::service1, YourService::service2, YourService::service3)
```

Streams will evaluate lazily, so using method references allows you take advantage of this and defer execution until needed.

```
    .map(supplier -> supplier.get())
```

The rest of your execution chain can work the way you have it.

```
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .findFirst()
    .ifPresent(this::doSomething);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a complete example:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stream<Supplier<String>> suppliers =
            Stream.of(() -> service1(), () -> service2(), () -> service3(), () -> service4());

        suppliers.map(Supplier::get)
                 .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                 .findFirst()
                 .ifPresent(System.out::println);
    }

    private static String service1() {
        System.out.println("service1");
        return null;
    }

    private static String service2() {
        System.out.println("service2");
        return null;
    }

    private static String service3() {
        System.out.println("service3");
        return "hello";
    }

    private static String service4() {
        System.out.println("service4");
        return "world";
    }
}
```

Comment: very cool!  I wrote up a very similar example to test this and it works great.  I'm going to mark this as the answer and thanks!!

Comment: @JB Nizet, how can we be sure that map won't be called for all suppliers?

Comment: We can be sure because findFirst() is a short-cicuiting terminal operation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--

Comment: Thanks, but it does not say anything about not processing some elements before terminating.

Comment: If it processed all the elements before terminating, it wouldn't be short-circuiting anymore, would it?

Comment: so.. what if I said those services can throw exceptions..?  This doesn't seem to work in that case.

Comment: Nevermind.  I answered my own question.  I created a functional interface called ExSupplier that can throw Exception and used that.  Thanks again.